# Applying random projection to a large sparse matrix

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn

I am doing a binary text classification and I have a large sparse matrix `(n_samples: 974, n_features: 19329)` which was a result of using bag of word representation .. I read the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/random_projection.html#johnson-lindenstrauss) for applying random projection on scikit-learn, and because there are different type of random projection I am not sure which one will suit my data better for example: since I have a sparse matrix can I apply The Sparse random projection or it expects a dense matrix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for the `fit` method, both [`GaussianRandomProjection`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.random_projection.GaussianRandomProjection.html#sklearn.random_projection.GaussianRandomProjection.fit) and [`SparseRandomProjection`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.random_projection.SparseRandomProjection.html#sklearn.random_projection.SparseRandomProjection.fit) support sparse inputs, so you can use both.